# Extract parameter from jQuery to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, puppeteer

I'm currently using Puppeteer and whenever I call this function, the "selector" is undefined.

```js
async function verifyTextPresent(page, selector){
  let myButton = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(selector).innerText);
  console.log(myButton);
}
```

ERROR:

```
(node:6996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: selector is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:20
(node:6996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: is this called before page is ready?

Comment: Do you have to pass in the `document` to the `evaluate` function? `page.evaluate(document => document.querySelector(selector).innerText)`. (Also, might be worth using `textContent` instead of `innerText`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the selector into evaluation like this:

```
async function verifyTextPresent(page, selector){
    let myButton = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
        document.querySelector(selector).innerText);
    }
    console.log(myButton);
}
```

I also prefer a shortcut using $eval:

```
let myButton = await page.$eval(selector, e => e.innerText);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Raul! I ended up with another solution but will try yours as it's simpler. Also, what's 'e'?

Comment: No problem, e for personal references is the element but you can give any name, it's a variable that holds your selector.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solutions changing the saw it gets the text:

```
async function verifyTextPresent(page, selector){
  let myButton= await page.$(selector);
  let selectorText = await (await elementForText.getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue();
      console.log(selectorText);
    }
```